# How do I strip the time from the summary property for the entity in a Lightswitch Desktop Client?

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch

In a Lightswitch Entity/Table I have a computed field called "DisplayName" which I use as the Summary Property for that Entity. The computed Property/Field contains the FirstName, LastName, Date of Birth and Primary Phone. Like this:

`partial void DisplayName_Compute(ref string result)
        {
            // Set result to the desired field value
            result = FirstName + " " + LastName + " " + DOB+" "+PrimaryPhone;`

In C#.

The DOB, for date of birth, has data type of "Date" in the Entity/Table.  In the List Column of a ListDetail screen in the desktop client application show the record as:

John Doe 01/17/1980 12:00:00 A.M. 555-555-5555
I would like to strip the time off so that it looks like this:

John Doe 01/17/1980 555-555-5555

Comment: Why don't you use String.Format with the culture of format string you want?

Answer (score 0):

This should hopefully work for your scenario :)

```
partial void DisplayName_Compute(ref string result)

        {
            //CREATE A DATETIME PARAMETER
            DateTime theDate = Convert.ToDateTime(entity.DOB);

            // Set result to the desired field value
            result = FirstName + " " + LastName + " " + theDate.Date + " " + PrimaryPhone;
        }
```

alternatively this will:

partial void DisplayName_Compute(ref string result)

```
        {
            //CREATE A DATETIME PARAMETER
            DateTime theDate = Convert.ToDateTime(entity.DOB);

            // Set result to the desired field value
            result = FirstName + " " + LastName + " " + theDate.ToString("dd.MM.yy") + " " + PrimaryPhone;
        }
```

Comment: Lightswitch does not allow you to use entity.DOB.Date, which is why the variable has been created

Comment: Didn't say anything about `.Date`. I said that `Convert.ToDateTime()` won't strip the time element. This is equivalent to the original code. Besides, you don't need to use `.Date` to format a DateTime string. Just use the appropriate format string

Comment: @Crezzer7  Great job. Works well. Thank you.

Comment: Actually such code generates extra temporary strings. That's why it's advised to avoid string concatenation and use String.Format. The format string is also wrong for the requested format. It will produce `17.01.80`, not `01/17/1980`.

Answer (score -1):

Use [String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) to generate a string from multiple parameters, using the format you want. In this case, it's:

```
var result=String.Format("{0} {1} {2:d} {3}",FirstName,LastName,DOB,PrimaryPhone");
```

This will return the date formatted using the appropriate short date format for the client's culture. If you want to hard-code this to the US format, you can pass the appropriate culture:

```
var result=String.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"),
                         "{0} {1} {2:d} {3}",FirstName,LastName,DOB,PrimaryPhone");
```

Comment: And the reason for the downvote is ... ? Given how String.Format is available everywhere, it's the proper way to format strings *and* produces the correct output ?

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos , I appreciate your time working on this. The reason I used Crezzar7's solution is because I know very little about this coding and on the face of it I did understand Crezzar7's answer immediately and was able to implement it. I had been spending hours and hours over the last couple of weeks searching this forum and others looking for a solution. Yours may be the better way but I have no way to know that. In the end I used ("MM/dd/yyyy" instead of  ("dd.MM.yy") .

Comment: String.Format is a pretty basic function. Besides, hard-coding the format will cause trouble if your application is used by someone with a different locale

Comment: I am trying your code on a different project and it is working except I am getting an error for the "result" that says "a local or parameter named 'result' cannot be declared in the scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local parameter"

Comment: I used the following ; '  partial void DisplayName_Compute(ref string result)
        {
            // Set result to the desired field value


            // result = FirstName + " " + LastName + " " + Created;
            var result = string.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), "{0} {1} {2:d} {3}", FirstName, LastName, Created, PrimaryPhone);

        }
    }
}'

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos, Are you able to respond? Or should I start a new question?

Comment: You already declared a parameter with that name. You can't declare a variable with the same name. Besides, there's no reason to use that parameter. .NET strings are reference types and immutable. There's no copying involved if you return the result directly